# How get hp-setup to install printer?

Tags: 12.04, plugins

I am trying to install and use Ubuntu 12.04 on my laptop without Windows.  I have an HP Laserjet 1020 printer but can't get it to print.  The printer looks like it is installed but won't print; not even a test page.  I am on a page that says, "This printer REQUIRES a downloadable driver plug-in.  Use hp-setup to intall the printer, and to download and install the plug-in." 
It appears that I have the printer installed but how do I get the plug in I need?  The message above did not give a name for the plug=in.

Answer (score 0):

Did you use HPLIP?
http://hplipopensource.com/hplip-web/downloads.html
you may also try to type "hp-setup" in terminal.

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone else stubbles upon this page, HP printers have great support in Linux.

hplip is the package you want.

```
sudo apt install hplip
```

At that point you need to run hp-setup, if you do not have pyqt5 installed you will need it if you want to use the graphical interface.

```
sudo apt python3-pyqt5
```

Now run

```
hp-setup -u
```

If you have a network printer I suggest you look at the printers network configuration and find out what the IP address is and set it as static.  Now enter the IP address you set into the HP Setup utility.

That is it.  You can now use your printer and/or scanner.

Answer (score 0):

If you've had a successful prior installation, this may help:  On a new computer, Ubuntu 22.04, I installed HPLIP successfully, but could not install the plugins necessary for the ancient HP LJ P1006 printer.  At a loss after several hours researching, downloading, installing, removing, reinstalling, etc., I went to a partition of the same HD that had a prior 22.04 installation (don't ask why.) The HP printer worked there.  I copied the .hplip folder, and pasted it into the new OS at the same spot (first deactivating the ineffective .hplip folder by renaming it.)  I rebooted and held my breath.  It worked!!!

Answer (score 0):

Are you able to use the system gui add printer dialogue? I have had great results with the HP jet driver. Select this driver, then put the URL of the printer in the box as shown on my screenshot.

[image]

Easy process. No command line, no driver install needed. I remember seeing someone else shared this online and it worked for me.

Answer (score -1):

How ever this is worked:

1. Switch ON Printer and Connect to your Laptop/PC
2. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd> to open terminal
3. run using the following commands :

   ```
   sudo apt-get install hplip
   sudo apt-get install hpijs-ppds
   sudo hp-setup -i
   ```

See commands / processes appear on the screen.

```
sreenatha@sreenatha-Inspiron-5570:~$ sudo apt-get install hplip
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
hplip is already the newest version (3.17.10+repack0-5).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 11 not upgraded.
sreenatha@sreenatha-Inspiron-5570:~$ sudo apt-get install hpijs-ppds
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following additional packages will be installed:
  printer-driver-hpijs
Suggested packages:
  hplip-doc
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  hpijs-ppds printer-driver-hpijs
0 upgraded, 2 newly installed, 0 to remove and 11 not upgraded.
Need to get 389 kB of archives.
After this operation, 2,392 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] Y
Get:1 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/main amd64 printer-driver-hpijs amd64 3.17.10+repack0-5 [296 kB]
Get:2 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/universe amd64 hpijs-ppds all 3.17.10+repack0-5 [93.4 kB]
Fetched 389 kB in 2s (199 kB/s)      
Selecting previously unselected package printer-driver-hpijs.
(Reading database ... 334612 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../printer-driver-hpijs_3.17.10+repack0-5_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking printer-driver-hpijs (3.17.10+repack0-5) ...
Selecting previously unselected package hpijs-ppds.
Preparing to unpack .../hpijs-ppds_3.17.10+repack0-5_all.deb ...
Unpacking hpijs-ppds (3.17.10+repack0-5) ...
Setting up printer-driver-hpijs (3.17.10+repack0-5) ...
Setting up hpijs-ppds (3.17.10+repack0-5) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.8.3-2ubuntu0.1) ...
Processing triggers for cups (2.2.7-1ubuntu2.7) ...
Updating PPD files for hpijs-ppds ...
Updating PPD files for hpijs ...
sreenatha@sreenatha-Inspiron-5570:~$ sudo hp-setup -i

HP Linux Imaging and Printing System (ver. 3.17.10)
Printer/Fax Setup Utility ver. 9.0

Copyright (c) 2001-15 HP Development Company, LP
This software comes with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY.
This is free software, and you are welcome to distribute it
under certain conditions. See COPYING file for more details.

(Note: Defaults for each question are maked with a '*'. Press <enter> to accept the default.)


--------------------------------
| SELECT CONNECTION (I/O) TYPE |
--------------------------------

  Num       Connection  Description                                               
            Type                                                                  
  --------  ----------  ----------------------------------------------------------
  0*        usb         Universal Serial Bus (USB)                                
  1         net         Network/Ethernet/Wireless (direct connection or JetDirect)
  2         par         Parallel Port (LPT:)                                      

Enter number 0...2 for connection type (q=quit, enter=usb*) ? )0*
error: Please enter a number between 0 and 2, or "q" to quit.

Enter number 0...2 for connection type (q=quit, enter=usb*) ? 0

Using connection type: usb


Setting up device: hp:/usb/HP_LaserJet_1020?serial=S44NWQ2



------------------------
| PLUG-IN INSTALLATION |
------------------------


HP Linux Imaging and Printing System (ver. 3.17.10)
Plugin Download and Install Utility ver. 2.1

Copyright (c) 2001-15 HP Development Company, LP
This software comes with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY.
This is free software, and you are welcome to distribute it
under certain conditions. See COPYING file for more details.

warning: It is not recommended to run 'hp-plugin' in a root mode.

HP Linux Imaging and Printing System (ver. 3.17.10)
Plugin Download and Install Utility ver. 2.1

Copyright (c) 2001-15 HP Development Company, LP
This software comes with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY.
This is free software, and you are welcome to distribute it
under certain conditions. See COPYING file for more details.

(Note: Defaults for each question are maked with a '*'. Press <enter> to accept the default.)


------------------------------------------
| PLUG-IN INSTALLATION FOR HPLIP 3.17.10 |
------------------------------------------

  Option      Description                                       
  ----------  --------------------------------------------------
  d           Download plug-in from HP (recommended)            
  p           Specify a path to the plug-in (advanced)          
  q           Quit hp-plugin (skip installation)                

Enter option (d=download*, p=specify path, q=quit) ? d

-------------------
| DOWNLOAD PLUGIN |
-------------------

Checking for network connection...
Downloading plug-in from: 
Downloading plug-in: [\                                   ] 0% Receiving digital keys: /usr/bin/gpg --homedir /home/sreenatha/.hplip/.gnupg --no-permission-warning --keyserver pgp.mit.edu --recv-keys 0x4ABA2F66DBD5A95894910E0673D770CDA59047B9

error: Unable to recieve key from keyserver
Do you still want to install the plug-in? (y=yes, n=no*, q=quit) ? y

----------------------
| INSTALLING PLUG-IN |
----------------------

Creating directory plugin_tmp
Verifying archive integrity... All good.
Uncompressing HPLIP 3.17.10 Plugin Self Extracting Archive................................................

HP Linux Imaging and Printing System (ver. 3.17.10)
Plugin Installer ver. 3.0

Copyright (c) 2001-15 HP Development Company, LP
This software comes with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY.
This is free software, and you are welcome to distribute it
under certain conditions. See COPYING file for more details.

Plug-in version: 3.17.10
Installed HPLIP version: 3.17.10
Number of files to install: 42

You must agree to the license terms before installing the plug-in:

LICENSE TERMS FOR HP Linux Imaging and Printing (HPLIP) Driver Plug-in          


These License Terms govern your Use of the HPLIP Driver Plug-in Software (the   
"Software"). USE OF THE SOFTWARE INCLUDING, WITHOUT LIMITATION, ANY             
DOCUMENTATION, IS SUBJECT TO THESE LICENSE TERMS AND THE APPLICABLE AS-IS       
WARRANTY STATEMENT. BY DOWNLOADING AND INSTALLING THE SOFTWARE, YOU ARE AGREEING
TO BE BOUND BY THESE TERMS. IF YOU DO NOT AGREE TO ALL OF THESE TERMS, DO NOT   
DOWNLOAD AND INSTALL THE SOFTWARE ON YOUR SYSTEM.                               


1. License Grant. HP grants you a license to Use one copy of the Software with  
HP printing products only. "Use" includes using, storing, loading, installing,  
executing, and displaying the Software. You may not modify the Software or      
disable any licensing or control features of the Software.                      


2. Ownership. The Software is owned and copyrighted by HP or its third party    
suppliers. Your license confers no title to, or ownership in, the Software and  
is not a sale of any rights in the Software. HP's third party suppliers may     
protect their rights in the Software in the event of any violation of these     
license terms.                                                                  


3. Copies and Adaptations. You may only make copies or adaptations of the       
Software for archival purposes or when copying or adaptation is an essential    
step in the authorized Use of the Software. You must reproduce all copyright    
notices in the original Software on all copies or adaptations. You may not copy 
the Software onto any public network.                                           


4. No Disassembly. You may not Disassemble the Software unless HP's prior       
written consent is obtained. "Disassemble" includes disassembling, decompiling, 
decrypting, and reverse engineering. In some jurisdictions, HP's consent may not
be required for limited Disassembly. Upon request, you will provide HP with     
reasonably detailed information regarding any Disassembly.                      


5. No Transfer. You may not assign, sublicense or otherwise transfer all or any 
part of these License Terms or the Software.                                    


6. Termination. HP may terminate your license, upon notice, for failure to      
comply with any of these License Terms. Upon termination, you must immediately  
destroy the Software, together with all copies, adaptations and merged portions 
in any form.                                                                    


7. Export Requirements. You may not export or re-export the Software or any copy
or adaptation in violation of any applicable laws or regulations.               


8. U.S. Government Restricted Rights. The Software has been developed entirely  
at private expense. It is delivered and licensed, as defined in any applicable  
DFARS, FARS, or other equivalent federal agency regulation or contract clause,  
as either "commercial computer software" or "restricted computer software",     
whichever is applicable. You have only those rights provided for such Software  
by the applicable clause or regulation or by these License Terms.               


9. DISCLAIMER OF WARRANTIES. TO THE MAXIMUM EXTENT PERMITTED BY APPLICABLE LAW, 
HP AND ITS SUPPLIERS PROVIDE THE SOFTWARE "AS IS" AND WITH ALL FAULTS, AND      
HEREBY DISCLAIM ALL OTHER WARRANTIES AND CONDITIONS, EITHER EXPRESS, IMPLIED, OR
STATUTORY, INCLUDING, BUT NOT LIMITED TO, WARRANTIES OF TITLE AND               
NON-INFRINGEMENT, ANY IMPLIED WARRANTIES, DUTIES OR CONDITIONS OF               
MERCHANTABILITY, OF FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE, AND OF LACK OF VIRUSES ALL
WITH REGARD TO THE SOFTWARE. Some states/jurisdictions do not allow exclusion of
implied warranties or limitations on the duration of implied warranties, so the 
above disclaimer may not apply to you in its entirety.                          


10. LIMITATION OF LIABILITY. Notwithstanding any damages that you might incur,  
the entire liability of HP and any of its suppliers under any provision of this 
agreement and your exclusive remedy for all of the foregoing shall be limited to
the greater of the amount actually paid by you separately for the Software or   
U.S. $5.00. TO THE MAXIMUM EXTENT PERMITTED BY APPLICABLE LAW, IN NO EVENT SHALL
HP OR ITS SUPPLIERS BE LIABLE FOR ANY SPECIAL, INCIDENTAL,                      
INDIRECT, OR CONSEQUENTIAL DAMAGES WHATSOEVER (INCLUDING, BUT NOT LIMITED TO,   
DAMAGES FOR LOSS OF PROFITS OR CONFIDENTIAL OR OTHER INFORMATION, FOR BUSINESS  
INTERRUPTION, FOR PERSONAL INJURY, FOR LOSS OF PRIVACY ARISING OUT OF OR IN ANY 
WAY RELATED TO THE USE OF OR INABILITY TO USE THE SOFTWARE, OR OTHERWISE IN     
CONNECTION WITH ANY PROVISION OF THIS AGREEMENT, EVEN IF HP OR ANY SUPPLIER HAS 
BEEN ADVISED OF THE POSSIBILITY OF SUCH DAMAGES AND EVEN IF THE REMEDY FAILS OF 
ITS ESSENTIAL PURPOSE. Some states/jurisdictions do not allow the exclusion or  
limitation of incidental or consequential damages, so the above limitation or   
exclusion may not apply to you.                                                 

Do you accept the license terms for the plug-in (y=yes*, n=no, q=quit) ? y

Done.

------------------------
| DOWNLOADING FIRMWARE |
------------------------


Downloading firmware to device hp:/usb/HP_LaserJet_1020?serial=S44NWQ2...
Firmware download successful.


Done.

---------------------
| PRINT QUEUE SETUP |
---------------------

warning: One or more print queues already exist for this device: HP-LaserJet-1020.

Would you like to install another print queue for this device (y=yes, n=no*, q=quit) ? error: User exit

Done.
```